# runtime permissions required in api less than 23?

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I'm creating an app with multiple apks. One for API 16-19, one for 21-22 and on for 23-29. Do i have to request runtime permissions in all the apks or just the third to pass the google review process?

Comment: Only from 23 and onwards you are required to ask run time permissions. On lower API, all permissions are accepted at install time. May I ask why you are creating three different APKs but not one that is dynamically adjusting to different API level?

Comment: I tried to include different .java files for the different API levels but i had problems with android studio and it seemed more easy to just create 3 apks. The problem is i've been rejected due to some runtime permissions issue and google says that you have to request runtime permission even if the apk targets API less than 23; so i'm asking just to be sure and not get rejected again. Please share a link about dynamically adjusting to different API level. Thanks!!

Comment: I would not recommend creating 3 different apps, though I don't have much knowledge of how Google passes apps but having 3 different apps that largely offer same functionality seems like a future suspension of apps. Edit the question and write down which permissions have you declared in the `Manifest` file. That "dynamically" is nothing but if/else conditions to check device API level and adjusting code flow to it, for example `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) //if current API level is Marshmallow or above, execute this code`